# How do I "disconnect" sockets in order to allow for reconnection

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I am creating a distributed computing server and the corresponding client Python. My server creates a daemon pool using multiprocessing which waits for connections from a client, then either sends data to the client. The client then performs an operation that can take up to 12 hours. After finishing, the client will send the data back.

Because the operations can take so long, I would like to be able to disconnect the server and the client sockets so the process can service more clients. However, I have only found functions to close the socket.

```
SERVER

111 def Worker(socket, lock):
122         "Workers follow this workflow"
123         while True:
124                 #Accept connection
125                 client, address = socket.accept()
126                 logger.debug("{u} connected".format(u=address))
127                 client.send("Connection established")
128                 #Receive orders
129                 orders = client.recv(1024)
130                 if orders == "REQUEST WORK":
131                         lock.acquire()
132                         jobname = findjob()
133                         lock.release()
134                         print jobname
135                         filenames = getjobfiles(jobname)
136                         #Send job description
137                         numfiles = len(filenames)
138                         desc = "SENDING " + jobname + " " + str(numfiles) + " "
139                         blank =''
140                         jobdesc = desc.replace('\n', blank)
141                         for i in filenames:
142                                 name = i.replace(Jobsdir, blank)
143                                 jobdesc += name
144                                 jobdesc += ' '
145                         client.send(jobdesc)
146                         ready = client.recv(1024)
147                         while ready != "READY":
148                                 ready = client.recv(1024)
149                         for i in filenames:
150                                 sendfile(client, i)
151                 elif orders == 'RETURN DATA':
152                         client.send('READY')
153                         #Receive information about files to be sent
154                         data = client.recv(1024)
155                         #Interpret data
156                         jobname, filenames = parse(data)
157                         numfiles = len(filenames)
158                         client.send('READY')
159                         #Receive all of the files from client
160                         for i in range(numfiles):
161                                 print 'RECEIVING ', filenames[i]
162                                 recvfile(client, jobname, filenames[i])
163                         #Lock and remove job from jobs list
164                         lock.acquire()
165                         removejob(jobname)
166                         lock.release()
167                         empty = jobsempty()
168                         if empty:
169                                 os.system('python Jobs/analyze.py')
170                                 print 'JOBS AND ANALYSIS FINISHED'
171                                 sys.exit(0)




 CLIENT

 80 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 81 #Get local machine name
 82 host = socket.gethostname()
 83 port = 5007
 84 while True:
 85         #Connect to server
 86         s.connect((host, port))
 87         #Receive confirmation of connection
 88         data = s.recv(1024)
 89         #Request work
 90         s.send('REQUEST WORK')
 91         #Receive string containing file names
 92         data = s.recv(1024)
 93         if data == 'NO NEW WORK': break
 94         #Get all files
 95         jobname, filenames = parse(data)
 96         os.mkdir(jobname)
 97         numfiles = len(filenames)
 98         print numfiles
 99         s.send('READY')
100         for i in range(numfiles):
101                 print i
102                 print 'RECEIVING ', filenames[i]
103                 recvfile(s, filenames[i])
104         print 'ALL FILES RECEIVED. CLOSING CONNECTION'
105         #Close socket
106         s.shutdown()
107         #Do work
108         os.system('python %s/orders.py'%jobname)
109         #After completing work, initiate another connection to send back files
110         time.sleep(4)
111         s.connect((host, port))
112         #Receive confirmation of connection
113         data = s.recv(1024)
114         #Tell server to prepare for incoming data
115         s.send('RETURN DATA')
116         data = s.recv(1024)
117         while data != 'READY':
118                 data = s.recv(1024)
119         #Tell server what is being sent back
120         newfilenames = getjobfiles(jobname)
121         newnumfiles = len(newfilenames)
122         desc = "SENDING " + jobname + " " + str(numfiles) + " "
123         blank = ''
124         jobdesc = desc.replace('\n', blank)
125         for i in filenames:
126                 jobdesc += name
127                 jobdesc += ' '
128         s.send(jobdesc)
129         #Wait for server to be ready
130         ready = s.recv(1024)
131         while ready != 'READY':
132                 ready = s.recv(1024)
133         #Send files
134         for i in filenames:
135                 sendfile(s, i)
136         s.recv(1024)
137         print 'ALL FILES SENT'
```

Is there a good way to do this? I'm sure there has to be a way.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like a bad idea. I don't see why you need a worker pool to back the socket connections. Just create a thread for each connection coming in. That way you can close and open connections at will.

Comment: Okay I'll look into this. Thanks!

Comment: You can't reconnect a socket once it has been disconnected; instead you have to create a new one and connect that.

Comment: So do I have to check that none of my processes are using the socket before I disconnect it, then connect it again? I suppose I could use a variable similar to a lock to implement this. I guess I could also give each process it's own socket. Is that how it's normally done?